# JaCoCo coverage configuration for a multi-module gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

We have a gradle project that has the following structure

```
root-project
|
|
---- core-module
|
|
---- feature-a
|
|
---- feature-b
|
|
---- integration-testing
```

The way that the code is organized is as follows

- In the core module, a list of public interfaces for the application's main functionalities is defined
- Each one of the feature modules implements a subset of the interfaces defined in the core module
- The integration-testing module has some tests written against the public interfaces defined in the core module

The build.gradle file of the integration-testing module looks like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core-module')
    // some other library dependencies

    runtimeOnly project(':feature-a')
    runtimeOnly project(':feature-b')
}
```

The idea is to have kind of a black-box testing setup where the test code knows only about the public interfaces and doesn't test any implementation details.

The problem that I am facing is how to properly configure a JaCoCo report that would include the percentage of the exported interfaces that are being covered.
With JaCoCo configuration looking like this

```
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = false
        html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('code-coverage')
    }
}

test {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // report is always generated after tests run
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

the coverage report is being generated just for the classes defined in the integration-testing module, but what I want to get is the percentage of the exported public interfaces that are being covered by the tests(merging coverage results from sub-modules here would not work as the feature-a/feature-b module do not contain the required tests by themselves).

Is it possible to achieve this type of coverage result with the current project structure?